# Remove a image when clicked with mouse javascript

Tags: javascript

So I was about to make my final project on codehs. I use javascript and came across this problem, so I have a target that is always moving and I have a crosshair which I want to be deleted when I click on it through `mouseClickMethod()`; I tried `getElementAt` and `getX` and `getY`.
Can anyone help me?

this is my  code:

```
var background;
var target; 
var horizontalLine;
var verticalLine;
var x;
var y;
var redBall;
var dx = 5;
var dy = 0;
var count = 0;

function start(){
    var play = readInt("Press 1 to start the game in easiest difficulty press 2 to play in normal difficulty and press 3 to play in hard difficulty ");
    if(play == 1){
        background();
        target = new WebImage("https://codehs.com/uploads/09d10ce42020f57b62bb51edf4af52b1");
        target.setPosition(-150,350);
        target.setSize(140,140);
        add(target);
        setTimer(drawTarget,0);
        mouseMoveMethod(crosshair);
    }
}


function background(){
    background = new WebImage("https://codehs.com/uploads/761ea7cf98a0159e6ab47e5f04194ce5");
    background.setSize(400,500);
    add(background);
    
}

function drawTarget(){
    count++;
    target.move(dx,dy);
    println(count);
    turnAround();
}

function turnAround(){
    if(count == 100){
        dx = -dx;
        count = 0;
    }
}
function crosshair(e){
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();
    remove(horizontalLine);
    remove(verticalLine);
    horizontalLine = new Line(e.getX(), 0, e.getX(), e.getY());
    horizontalLine.setEndpoint(e.getX() - 0 ,e.getY() - 0);
    horizontalLine.setLineWidth(1);
    add(horizontalLine);
 
    verticalLine = new Line(x, 0, x, getHeight());
    verticalLine.setEndpoint(x - 0 ,y - 0);
    verticalLine.setLineWidth(1);
    add(verticalLine);
 
    remove(horizontalLine);
    remove(verticalLine);
    
    horizontalLine = new Line(0, y, getWidth(), y);
    horizontalLine.setLineWidth(1);
    add(horizontalLine);
 
    verticalLine = new Line(x, 0, x, getHeight());
    verticalLine.setLineWidth(1);
    add(verticalLine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here how you can easily remove an element from the dom:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_remove.asp

```js
const el = document.querySelector('#image');
const rmv = () => el.remove();

el.addEventListener('click', rmv)
```

```html
<img src="" id="image" alt="i will be removed after click"/>
```

Comment: Well I'm on codeHS (programming learning website) I have not learned those yet so I cant use them.

Comment: https://codehs.com/share/id/write-the-code-QPtTVo/run this is what my code does